# Regex match two strings but not third (in random order)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match two strings without one particular string (order of these doesn't count)

Searched words: "seadvert" AND "google" AND (NOT "none")

```
query.php?refererURL=partner_cid=seadvert&google=&none=true
```

is okay

```
(?=.*seadvert)(?=.*google)(?!.*?none)
```

works for this string:

```
query.php?refererURL=partner_cid=seadvert&google&none
```

but doesn't work for this one:

```
query.php?refererURL=&none=true&partner_cid=seadvert&google
```

Comment: Are you trying to match them literally, or just the values of `partner_cid`? Also there is no string `google` in your example...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the introductory [tour] some time. Does this post really look like you wanted it to? You may want to read [How do I format my post?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and then [edit] it.

Comment: Literally, You are right, it should be google (instead of yahoo)

Comment: I don't undestand you. Do you want to match `none` or not? What about this query.php?

Comment: I wan't to match words seadvert, yahoo and not none.  (?=.*seadvert)(?=.google)(?!.?none) does the thing for link referer=seadvert&google=true  also for  referer=google&seadvert ... the thing is if there is a string referer=seadvert&google=true&none - it should not match and if referer=none&seadvert&google=true  it should not match

Comment: Just FYI, I went ahead and corrected the examples, replacing all instances "yahoo" with "google".

Comment: @MarcinJędra: can you provide some feedback on the solution provided? If it does not work for you please gives a failing path, i'll try to adjust the regex as well.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a possible implementation:

```
^                     # start of the line
  (?=.*\bseadvert\b)  # require "seadvert" (not substring)
  (?=.*\bgoogle\b)    # require "google" (not substring)
  (?:(?!\bnone\b).)*  # assure no "none" in the string and actually consume it
$                     # end of the line
/mx                   # multiline and extended modifier (both not strictly required)
```

An [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/vC7gQ0/2)

Answer (score 0):

You need to a do a negative lookahead (`(?!.*none)`) to search for `none`, which if is found will not match the other groups.

```
^(?!.*\bnone\b).*(google|seadvert).*
```

[image]

https://regex101.com/r/gI4wZ7/2

Comment: He said *both* "google" and "seadvert" must be present  Your regex only requires one of them.  As a matter of fact, the OP's regex is fine except for the missing anchor.